# Laravel5 and PHPUnit with code coverage: Segmentation fault after Authentication

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, code-coverage

I use PHPUnit with code coverage on my Laravel 5 project on MAC OS X 10.9.5. I wrote a test class for a client profile page as follows.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class MinimalViewTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testWithSegFault()
    {
        ...

        $this->actingAs($userAuthorized)
             ->visit('/clients/profile/x11')
             ->visit('/clients/profile/' . $randomUser->id);
    }
}
```

The test visits two different pages as an authorized user. The first visit to `/clients/profile/x11` succeeds. However, the second visit ends in a segmentation fault.

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -v tests/MinimalViewTest.php
PHPUnit 5.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.0 with Xdebug 2.4.0
Configuration: /.../phpunit.xml

Segmentation fault: 11
```

If I call PHPUnit with no code coverage, the test succeeds.

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit -v tests/MinimalViewTest.php --no-coverage
PHPUnit 5.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.0 with Xdebug 2.4.0
Configuration: /.../phpunit.xml

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.71 seconds, Memory: 16.00Mb

OK (1 test, 3 assertions)
```

Besides the authentication provided by Laravel 5, I use my own middleware to determine the user group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'usergroup'], 'groups' => ['admin', 'orgateam']], function ()
{
    Route::get('/clients/profile/{clientsId}', ['as' => 'clientsProfileByClientId', 'uses' => 'ClientsController@profileByClientId']);
});
```

The middleware I use is as follows.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as Auth;

class UserGroupMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I could track the issue down to the call `$next($request)` that raises the segmentation fault. However, I am able to var_dump both objects `$next` and `$request` with no problem.

I used gdb to find more hints on why the segmentation fault occurs. It points me to

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff88a7fd13 in _platform_strcmp ()
   from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
```

What is happening here precisely? Is there really an issue with the Authentication of Laravel 5 and PHPUnit code coverage? I would really like to use code coverage along with PHPUnit.

Comment: Did you find the solution on this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: I found the solution. I had installed phpunit 4.x. I run the test on a docker php 7 image. When i upgraded phpunit from 4.x to 5.5.x, everything works perfect. The error was not displayed on phpunit 4.x on php 5.6.x. Only on php7